# PhpStorm + JSCS + TWIG with JavaScript. JSCS doesn't work

Tags: twig, phpstorm, jscs

JSCS is installed correctly and I have tested it with a .js file.

When I am editing a .html.twig or .js.twig JSCS doesn't kick in.

PhpStorm detects that it's a HTML and JS file.

Is it possible for JSCS to work in PhpStorm when editing twig files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSCS supports `--extract` option that allows linting embedded javascript (http://jscs.info/overview). But:

- only html format is supported (JavaScript inside `<script>` is checked)
- PHPStorm doesn't currently support this option, as it doesn't work reliably (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-19491#comment=27-1307471)